# Anyone know where the 'Create a App' page is on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to add facebook features to my web app, in order to do this I need the app ID/API Key and App Secret. But when I click Apps from the developers page I just get pushed to my pages and theres no option to create a app. I have even tried going through the help centre link but still no joy anyone out there able to help?

Comment: Have you signed up for developers.facebook.com and was it approved? It happens from time to time that facebook add some extra verification before you can use all features of developers.facebook.com (Give us your id...happend to me).

Comment: ye i believe so I confirmed the e-mail etc, how would I go about checking if I have or not? I have even tried two e-mail address to see if that works but still the same issue.